# When building android project with ant debug command, my apk has the word debug attached to the name. How i change it?

Tags: android, debugging, ant, build, apk

I use "ant debug" to build my project. After building with this command, my apk name is sample-debug.apk (My project name is sample). I want it to be sample.apk after building it. How can i do this by modifying the build.xml.

please do not suggest me to rename the apk after it is built.

Comment: Savvy programmers leave the `-debug` in place. That is because savvy programmers find it important to distinguish the debug build (`-debug`) from the unsigned release build (`-release-unsigned`) and the signed release build (no suffix). The latter is what you would distribute via Google Play or other means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no technical reason to change the name, but if you want to you can over-ride the underlying ant task that sets the debug parameters. Currently it looks like this:

```
<target name="-set-debug-files" depends="-set-mode-check">
    <property name="out.packaged.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/${ant.project.name}-debug-unaligned.apk" />
    <property name="out.final.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/${ant.project.name}-debug.apk" />
    <property name="build.is.mode.set" value="true" />
</target>
```

You can paste that into your local build.xml above the import statement and change the values to whatever suits you.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should change the name of your .apk-file. I just found a description on the first paragraph of page 265 of this google book snippet [Pro Android Python with Sl4a](http://books.google.ch/books?id=y7xL8S2Z320C&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=ant%20debug%20rename%20apk&source=bl&ots=quU1LJrHlH&sig=s6leZmPf3Io73_gmE8WvxMnnxG4&hl=de&sa=X&ei=C3tsT7TyMI6JhQf5n8CSBw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAg). With this name convention, you can easily see what type the apk-file is you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.Refer this link [1]: https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

So in the above case,we need to run debug like this,

ant debug -Dout.final.file=brandA.apk

Thats it.